# How to prevent Flutter Html rebuild widget?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-html

when I use  [flutter_html: ^2.2.1](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html) .When I emit state(bloc pattern) in view data in Html widget auto rebuild . Can you help me prevent widget rebuild ? thank a lot

Comment: You can check this library as well . https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_widget_from_html

Comment: Showing us your code will help find the cause of the rebuilds.